# AJAX on localhost using IIS and php and MySQL

Tags: php, ajax, iis-7

I am trying AJAX for the first time on my localhost.
I am using IIS and PHP with MySQL.
This error is generated: "A HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found" when I try this javascript command:
         xmlhttp.send(null);

xmlhttp is a varable and is used to retrieve the GetXmlHttpObject

Comment: I think you need to expand on this a little more.

Comment: Yes, can you post the code as without any more information, we cannot really help....

Comment: additionally, you could look in the logs to see what resource the request is looking for.

Comment: I think the problem might be with the PHP.  In addition to posting an AJAX command, the javascript actualy calls php to get something from the database.

How do I make sure PHP is working properly on a localhost?

Comment: You should be able to just request your PHP script via the browser. Have a look at setting up Eclipse with the PHP Debugger to help you step through your PHP code.

Comment: I have done what I thought I needed to do to set up PHP.  But maybe this is where the problem lies.  I have gone into the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and I have added the Sript Map such that the request path is *.php   and the executable is C:\Program Files\PHP\php5.dll and the name is PHP.  Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: I have narrowed down my problem to the mysql_connect call I am doing in php.  It produces an error message.  What would you suggest I should do?

Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. 

Detailed Error Information
Module IsapiModule 
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler PHP 
Error Code 0x00000000 
Requested URL http://localhost:80/getuser.php?q=3&sid=0.2953613724031635 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\getuser.php 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in-case something inside your xmlhttp object creation is not setup correctly or you have not waited for the correct status, have you looked at some simple xamples like from [XUL.fr](http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html) or [W3 Shools](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) or [Your HTML Source](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/ajax.html)?

Below is a simple example. Notice the inline function for the onreadystatechange callback and the check on readystate and status. I believe your issue may reside in you note doing these checks, but without your code I could be wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function submitForm()
{ 
    var xhr; 
    try {  xhr = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');   }
    catch (e) 
    {
        try {   xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');    }
        catch (e2) 
        {
          try {  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();     }
          catch (e3) {  xhr = false;   }
        }
     }

    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function()
    { 
         if(xhr.readyState  == 4)
         {
              if(xhr.status  == 200) 
                  document.ajax.dyn="Received:"  + xhr.responseText; 
              else 
                 document.ajax.dyn="Error code " + xhr.status;
         }
    }; 

   xhr.open(GET, "data.txt",  true); 
   xhr.send(null); 
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <FORM method="POST" name="ajax" action="">                  
         <INPUT type="BUTTON" value="Submit"  ONCLICK="submitForm()">
         <INPUT type="text" name="dyn"  value=""> 
    </FORM>
 </body>
 </html>
```